# Running IBM MQ dmpmqcfg results in 'libmqds_r.dylib' error

Tags: ibm-mq

I am going to answer this myself as a FAQ.

This has been seen on MacOS, but applies to all MQ Client only installations. When running `dmpmqcfg` in a terminal you see the error:

```
AMQ8670E: Loading of server module 'libmqds_r.dylib' failed.
```

Comment: Be careful to be accurate. When you say "all MQ Client environments" what you mean is "all MQ Client only installations" - not the same thing. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `dmpmqcfg` is used to dump the configuration of IBM MQ queue managers. It needs to connect to a queue manager to do this. `dmpmqcfg` can run both in bindings and client mode. The error is thrown when `dmpmqcfg` is run in bindings mode on a client only install, and is thrown when it can't find the .dylib file being requested. `libmqds_r.dylib` is used to make a bindings connection, which only works when its co-located on the MQ server.

If you see this error on a client machine, then you need to run `dmpmqcfg` in client mode:

```
dmpmqcfg -c
```

and provide queue manager information on the command line, or through a CCDT, or mqclient.ini